# reactjs create dynamic wrapper element in map()

Tags: loops, render, reactjs

i have issues to probably understand ReactJS well enough to create dynamic div wrapper in every five steps. To be more specific here is an example:

```jsx
render() {
    return (
            <div className='holder'>
              {this.props.elements.map(
                (b,n) => 
                  {n%5 == 0 ? '<div class="grid grid-pad">' : ''}
                  <Component param={b} />
                  {n%5 == 0 ? '</div>' : ''}                 
              )}
            </div>
     )
}
```

The results should look like this:

```jsx
<div class='grid grid-pad'>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
</div>
<div class='grid grid-pad'>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  ...
</div>
....
```

So the result would be that every 5 elements would be wrapped in div.

I am aware that this is not the right way, at this code actually it produces errors for not closed tags. Is there any way how to actually achieve similar functionality. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can't dynamically create a React component from a string quite like that. You'll just need to group the children manually and add them as a whole to a container within the `render` method.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/wiredprairie/ko8so1mu/.

If you were using something like `lodash`, you could reduce the number of lines of code below by using the `take` function.

```jsx
render() {
    // make all elements into Components
    var elements = this.props.elements || [];
    var components = elements.map(
        (b) => {
            return <Component param={b} />;
        }
    );

    // then just group into chunks of 5 
    var groups = [];
    var children = [];
    while(components.length > 0) {
        children.push(components.shift());
        if (children.length === 5) {
            groups.push(<div className="grid grid-pad">{children}</div>);
            children = [];
        }
    }
    // remaining children
    if (children.length > 0 ) {
        groups.push(<div className="grid grid-pad">{children}</div>);
    }

    return (
        <div className='holder'>
          { groups }
        </div>
     );
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, this is actually what I was looking for. But thanks to every body else too. It is great to have people around who can help!

Answer (score 0):

This is how you could do it:

```jsx
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var Parent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      list: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
    }
  },
  render: function() {
    return(
      <div>
        <Child elements={this.state.list} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var Child = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var itemsList = this.props.elements.map(function(element, index) {
      if (index % 5 == 0) {
        return (
          <div> {element} </div>
        );
      }
    });

    return(
      <div>
        {itemsList}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

React.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

You keep the data in the `Parent` component then pass it to the `Child` component in `props`.

if you do `console.log(itemsList)` you can see what is happening inside `map()` method.

Here is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/36v4fjdy/1/).

---

**Edit:**

After you updated your question, here is something I quickly hacked, this is not the best way of doing it, but it works:

```jsx
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var Parent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      list: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
    }
  },
  render: function() {
    return(
      <div>
        <Child elements={this.state.list} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});


var Child = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
      var arr_index = -1;
      var itemsList = [];
      var items = this.props.elements.map(function(item, i) {
        if (i % 5 == 0) {
          arr_index += 1
        }
        itemsList.push(<div> {item}, conatiner: {arr_index} </div>)
      });
      return (
        <div>{itemsList}</div>
      );
    }
});

React.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

You still need to tweak it a bit to meet your requirements, but basically it divides children into "containers", I guess that's what you were looking for.

Comment: This is really nice, but actually I do not think it solves my issue. But that is probably my error to ask the question badly. I want it the result be something like this:

<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
</div>

So the result would be that every 5 elements would be wrapped in div.

Comment: @LukášJahoda I've updated my answer, let me know if this is what you wanted

Comment: Thank you! But I guess that this is what I am looking for, but I was not able to meet my wanted result.. :(

Comment: @LukášJahoda do you still need help with this?

Comment: if you still have time and good soul to help me with the exact result I need I would be really pleased. Thank you in advance.